# How can I change `embed` element for `img` element in rich text image Wagtail API response?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I'm using the Wagtail API to retrieve data of the pages from my site. The problem I'm having is that when there is an image inside a rich text block and I retrieve it using the API, the body attribute has the shape:

```
"body": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text",
            "value": "<p>some text</p>\n<p><embed alt=\"Some alt text"\" embedtype=\"image\" format=\"fullwidth\" id=\"68810\"/></p>"
        },
```

It means, the API returns an `embed` element instead of an `img` element with the source of the image, I want to change this response by having the `img` element.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding a custom serializer:

```
from rest_framework.fields import ReadOnlyField
from wagtail.rich_text import expand_db_html


class BlogPostBodySerializer(ReadOnlyField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        return expand_db_html(representation)
```

and then pointing to it from the APIField in the model definition:

```
APIField("body", serializer=BlogPostBodySerializer()),
```